# Sending mail using gmail server in play framewrok

Tags: playframework, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send mail using gmail server in my play app but it gives time out. I configured it as stated in the play documentation. my configuration is

```
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.user=******* 
mail.smtp.pass=*******
mail.smtp.channel=ssl.
```

It was sending successfully a couple of days ago. Is there anyone who knows the solution?

Comment: has your password changed? are you behind a firewall maybe? I use these same settings, and it works fine.

Comment: I did not change my password, firewall setting is same, but I changed my network. I am in a private network now. Could this be the reason?

Comment: can you ping smtp.gmail.com? If you can't then it is your network. My suspicion is that your network is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

- Are you using google apps for domain? Did you specify your domain in user name?
- Remove "." from "ssl.".
- Verify that you don't have "mail.smtp=mock" anywhere in your conf file.
- Verify that you're not overriding mail configuration somewhere later in file.
- Try to login manually with your account, check if you can send email, maybe you sent too  - many emails and you're temporary banned by gmail smtp.

Following works perfectly for me:

```
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.user=***@yourdomain.com
mail.smtp.pass=***
mail.smtp.channel=ssl
```

Comment: I found the the reason. My network administrator closed outgoing connections from port 25 and 465. I run my app in a different netwrok, now it works as expected.